# prototype into jquery migration problem

Tags: jquery, prototypejs

i try to migrate prototype to jquery. i start with

```
if (visible) {
        $(name + "_area").setStyle1({ display: 'block' });
    }
    else {
        $(name + "_area").setStyle1({ display: 'none' });   
    }
```

and i chnage to

```
function SetAreaVisibility(visible, name) {
if (visible) {
    $(#' + name + '_area').css('display', 'block'); 
}
else {
    $(#' + name + '_area').css('display', 'none'); 
}
```

which not working like i thing. is this correct code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what is name+"area" ?
if it's an id you'll have to write:

```
$('#'+name+'_area')
```

or

```
$('.'+name+'_area')
```

for classes. just like css.

Comment: my big mistake i forget about ' and i lost more then an hour for this. thx for seeing this.

Comment: +1 for this answer. In addition, you might opt to use $('.'+name+'_area').show() and .hide().